# Creating new data entity for RecId

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I need to get product URL of commerce via Data Export - however I have not found a way of getting expect building it from store domain and product RecId.
I created a new data-entity and drag&dropped RecId from the entity I inherit - but it still does not appear in the csv export/mapping.

Any ideas how to achieve this task?

Comment: There are several Microsoft Dynamics products (CRM, Retail, Finance, Operations, ...), can you specify the applicable product in your question please? For Finance/Operations: have you already done a [data entity refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-entities#entity-list-refresh)?

Comment: Hi, I am using Finance/Operations (Headquarters as I was told),

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding field to staging table and creating mapping with RecId.